# how to initialize static array within struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, initialization, static-array

I have this struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int start;
    int end;
    char board[10][10]; 
} move;
```

when I try initializing it this way:

```
char new_board[10][10]
move struct new_move = {0, 0, new_board}
```

I get this error:

warning C4047: 'initializing' : 'char' differs in levels of indirection from 'char (*)[10]'

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to initialize the array by zeroes then you can write simply

```
move new_move = { 0 };
```

If you want that the structure array would contain values of array `char new_board[10][10]` then you have to copy its element in the structure array.

for example

```
char new_board[10][10] = { /* some initializers */ };

move new_move = { 0 };

memcpy( new_move.board, new_board, sizeof( new_board ) );
```

If `board` is an array of strings then you could also to copy using a loop each string in the structure array using standard C function `strcpy`.

Answer (score -1):

First - the reason why you can't do this: if you do something like this you are saying to the compiler that you're trying to overwrite a constant pointer (a table is a constant pointer).

You can initialize the array by using two four loops like this:

```
int i, j
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        new_move.board[i][j] = new_board[i][j];
```

That should work best in my opinion.